# How do i get JavaScript to show number instead of strings

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm quite new to javascript and im trying to make this thing where i enter 2 values and it will either plus, multiply, divide etc. from what i enter in the code. But somehow when i try to multiply 5*2 it will show 10 but when i try 5+2 it will show 52, how do i fix this? I tried parseInt() but it didnt work

[Output][1]

Code:

```js
function myfunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var y = document.getElementById("lname").value;
var z = x + y;

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = z;
```

```html
<form>
<input type="Number" id="fname" value="" ><br><br>
<input type="number" id="lname" value="" ><br><br>


</form>

<button type="button" onclick="myfunction()">submit</button>

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: I found this article really helpful https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the values to `Number`s first. The `.value` from an element will always be a string.

```js
function myfunction() {
var x = Number(document.getElementById("fname").value);
var y = Number(document.getElementById("lname").value);
var z = x + y;

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = z;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="Number" id="fname" value="" ><br><br>
<input type="number" id="lname" value="" ><br><br>


</form>

<button type="button" onclick="myfunction()">submit</button>

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Is this question really worth an answer? ...

Comment: Math.round also work :)

Comment: So i just add Number in front of it and it will always return a number instead of string?

Comment: @Zenoo if you are here to just be mean you can leave, not everyone is a pro

Comment: But anyways  this worked! thank you very much

Comment: @Philip I'm not mean. I linked you the answer to your question. This question has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 0):

This is because both `x` & `y` is string.Use `parseInt` to convert the string to number before doing mathematical operation

```js
function myfunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  console.log(typeof x) // string
  var z = parseInt(x, 10) + parseInt(y, 10);

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = z;

}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="Number" id="fname" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="number" id="lname" value=""><br><br>


</form>

<button type="button" onclick="myfunction()">submit</button>

<p id="output"></p>
```